# How to animate a Flutter widget whose position changes due to layout changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm asking the same question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582454/animate-position-of-a-widget-in-flutter), except in their case they were able to solve the problem with a Hero animation which is not applicable here.  The situation I have is that when a user focuses a search field, the keyboard will appear and shift the content upward.  I would like to be able to animate that content upward so that it doesn't jump (and animate its motion also when the keyboard is dismissed), but the locations are entirely layout-dependent, meaning I can't know what the final position will be in order to use something like a SlideTransition.

Attached is a screenshot of my current situation.  The centered magnifying glass icon and text are the widget group that I would like to animate.

[image: Current state]

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563854/how-to-animate-flutter-layout-on-keyboard-appearance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the solution is dependent on a couple of things - one is that I had to set the `resetToAvoidBottomInset` property on my `Scaffold` widget to false, but in addition I had to use an `AnimatedPadding` widget that applies a padding to the bottom of my centered content that is equal to the `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` value which accounts for space taken up by the keyboard.  This certainly works but feels odd that I'm relying on knowledge of what's happening outside of the widget in order to provide an animation.

Here's a sample of the relevant code:

```dart
Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: AnimatedPadding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                  child: Center(
```

[image: Desired outcome]

Answer (score 0):

Just set property `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` in your `Scaffold` to `false`.

Comment: That does prevent the content from resizing, but I don't think the content resizing is the issue here.  I would still be left with the problem of somehow knowing the size of the area that the content moves within, and then determining where its "center" is so I know where to translate to.